# How can I generate a list while ignoring records that have a date that does not fit into the range I am looking for?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am using Microsoft SQL Server, I currently have a table with records for accounts. These master accounts can have several sub accounts linked to them. For example, master account XXX can have sub account XXXA and XXXB and... XXXN and so on and so forth.

These sub accounts can be opened and added to the master account XXX across time, so at different points in time. When a new sub account is opened, it also opens a new master account. From that point on, other sub accounts can be added to that master account number.

I have a column with the account opening dates. These dates are linked to when the sub accounts are opened.

I am trying to generate a list of master accounts (not sub accounts), that were opened between 2018-11-01 and 2019-02-15. However, I only want to include new MASTER ACCOUNTS, therefore ignoring any master accounts that have an account opening date prior to 2018-11-01.

The issue I am having is master accounts that are showing up in my generated list because they have sub accounts that have been added to them during the date ranges I am looking for.

I Have tried using the MIN function inside of having on my dates. I have checked other stack overflow threads for a solution as well

```
SELECT master_accounts, accountopendate, accountclosedate
FROM accounts
GROUP BY master_accounts, accountopendate, accountclosedate
HAVING MIN(accountopendate) BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2019-02-15';
```

It gave me a list of the master accounts, however upon doing some QA, I find some master accounts in the list, that have been opened prior to 2018-11-01.

I would like a list of master accounts with the oldest account opening date being 2018-11-01, ignoring all the master accounts with account opening dates prior to 2018-11-01.

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| master_accounts | accountopendate | accountclosedate |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| XXX             | 2018-11-01      | NULL             |
| ZZZ             | 2018-12-01      | NULL             |
| YYY             | 2019-02-01      | NULL             |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be really helpful here.

Comment: If you GROUP BY `accountopendate` then every row is its own MIN `accountopendate` and you're really not filtering anything.  If you only want a list of master accounts, why are you including the open and close dates in the SELECT list?   What values do you want for those columns if there are more than one row?

Comment: the dates are too allow me to filter the list afterwards once I export the results to Excel

Comment: Then Larnu is right, we need to see a set of sample data and results to understand what you are trying to do.   The question is too unclear.

Comment: You've done a good job laying out what you want, but not so much laying out what you have to work with to accomplish it. Have a look [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tools to help you edit your question as needed. Sample data here will go along way towards getting you some assistance.

Comment: I have added a pic to show a result if what I am expecting

Comment: Don't post a snippet of your data as an image. have a look at that link from @EricBrandt . Notice it says to provide a script. A tiny image isn't going to help us here.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the query doesn't know it should only be looking at master accounts. There's not enough information provided to help you find a programmatic way to distinguish the master accounts from the sub accounts.

Comment: There's no way to tell the query: for the date range provided, give me the master accounts however if the master account has an open date linked to it that's older than the date range, do not include it in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming the earliest opening date is always going to include the master account number.

First, isolate the account numbers and the initial opening date, then join that result set to your base table. I used a `CTE`, but a `sub-query` would accomplish the same thing.

Using a `CTE`:

```
WITH masterOpen AS
  (
    SELECT
      master_accounts
     ,MIN(accountopendate) AS openDate
    FROM
      dbo.accounts
    GROUP BY
      master_accounts
  )
SELECT
  a.master_accounts
 ,a.accountopendate
 ,a.accountclosedate
FROM
  dbo.accounts AS a
JOIN
  masterOpen AS mo
    ON
      mo.master_accounts = a.master_accounts
      AND 
      mo.openDate = a.accountopendate
      AND 
      mo.openDate >= '2018-11-01' 
      AND 
      mo.openDate <= '2019-02-15';
```

`Sub-query` instead:

```
SELECT
  a.master_accounts
 ,a.accountopendate
 ,a.accountclosedate
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      master_accounts
     ,MIN(accountopendate) AS openDate
    FROM
      dbo.accounts
    GROUP BY
      master_accounts
  ) AS mo
JOIN
  dbo.accounts AS a
    ON
      mo.master_accounts = a.master_accounts
      AND 
      mo.openDate = a.accountopendate
      AND 
      mo.openDate >= '2018-11-01' 
      AND 
      mo.openDate <= '2019-02-15';
```

The date parameters could also be broken out into a `WHERE` clause if you prefer, but with an `INNER JOIN` it will yield the same results. For current versions of the SQL engine, it's more a matter of preference than performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use filter

```
SELECT distinct master_accounts, accountopendate, accountclosedate
FROM accounts where accountopendate>='2018-11-01' AND accountopendate<='2019-02-15'
```

Comment: The problem is this filter will give me master accounts that have been opened from before 2018-11-01, because the open dates are linked to sub accounts and not master accounts. There may be some sub accounts opened after 2018-11-01 so they will be included in the results. I only want master accounts for which the first sub accounts were opened inbetween those two dtaes

Comment: @Puggy then use join between two tables and put filter condition based on masters account